# How do you register your application to use the Office 365 Outlook REST API?

Tags: outlook, office365api, office365-apps

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api) isn't clear on how to register your application to access the Office 365 outlook REST API. The documentation seems to say to go to the [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps-dev.dev.microsoft.com/), but logging in with 3 different accounts fails.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Application Registration Portal, you need either an Office 365 work or school account, or a Microsoft account. If you don't have either of these, you have a number of options:

- While you can use any Microsoft account to register applications, in order to access mail/calendar/contacts you need an upgraded Outlook.com account with the REST APIs enabled. To get an upgraded Outlook.com account, you could click [here](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/GetStarted) for solutions
- obtain an Office 365 subscription ,also refer to above link for details.

If you register App in Microsoft Application Registration Portal, the app only support V2 authentication endpoints.

Another choice is to register your app with Azure AD ,so your application could use  the OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant Flow, or need to  access other Office 365 workloads besides Outlook (such as OneDrive for Business or SharePoint).

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually) includes detail steps about manually register your app with Azure AD so it can access Office 365 APIs .